# Entropy of an infinite sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, information-theory, entropy

Does an infinite sequence always have finite entropy? For example, doesn't $a_n=n$, the sequence of non-negative integers, have very low entropy? It feels like all "well-defined" sequences ought to have low entropy because there's very little surprise about the next element.

Comment: In what sense are you assigning entropy to a sequence? I am writing an answer assuming that the sequence is representative of a string of outputs of a random process (and as such, the entropy of such a process is independent of the order of the symbols involved).

Comment: @probably_someone I don't exactly know. It feels like the entropy of a system is related to how "difficult" it is to describe it in closed form. So I think anything you write will be helpful for my understanding

Comment: It might be useful to familiarize yourself with what the quantitative definition of entropy actually is, then. The Wikipedia page has a decent treatment of it.

Comment: @probably_someone Would a better question be "what is the entropy of system _X_ which produces infinite sequence _Y_" (given well-defined _X_ and _Y_)?

Comment: Depends on what question you're trying to ask, and what your definition of a "system" is. The quantitative definition of entropy involves the output of a _stochastic_ process, i.e. one that exhibits random behavior and is described by a set of probabilities of producing a particular output. If this does not describe what you think a system is, then entropy may not be the quantity that describes what you want to measure.

Comment: Your example of $a_n = n$ suggests the concept that you want is closer to Kolmogorov complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). This is finite for any computable sequence but you might regard it as being infinite for all uncomputable sequences.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes sense if the terms of your series are all positive and the series converges.
For example if $A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, then you can define the probability distribution $p_n=a_n/A$. Hence, using the entropy definition $S=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n\ln p_n$, which is the standard definition of statistical mechanics divided by the Boltzmann constant $k_B$. For example, we could define then the entropy of Riemann's zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$. Using the probability distribution $p_n(s)=1/(\zeta(s)n^s)$, we obtain the "entropy" of the
zeta function:
\begin{align}
S(s) &= \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\ln(\zeta(s)n^s)=\ln\zeta(s)+\frac{s}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{n^s}=\ln\zeta(s)-\frac{s}{\zeta(s)}\zeta'(s)\\
&=\ln\zeta(s)-s\frac{d\ln\zeta(s)}{ds}
\end{align}
This is called the zeta distribution.
See here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution
Another example is the Poisson distribution, which you can obtain from the
expansion of $e^{\lambda t}$. The probability distribution you get from this
is $p_n=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague.

In the context of the Shannon entropy, one natural and usual measure of the "rate of information" of an infinite sequence (more aptly: of a discrete time stochastic process) is the entropy rate:

$$H_r = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{H(X_1,X_2 , \cdots H_n)}{n}$$

... if the limit exists, of course. Notice also that this is not the information of a single full sequence, but a normalized expected value.

Typically,  $0< H_r < \infty$, and and in that case the entropy of the infinite sequence is infinite.
In particular, if the sequence is produced by a stationary memoryless source (independent symbols with stationary distribution) then $H(X_1,X_2 , \cdots H_n)=n H(X_1)$ and $H_r = H(X_1)$

A little more general: for a stationary first order Markov process, $H_r = H(X_2 \mid X_1)$

If each symbol is totally predictable from the previous one, then $H_r=0$.

In your case, your sequence is not only predictable but also deterministic, hence $H_r=0$

This is not the end of the story, though. Because the Shannon entropy requires a probabilistic setting, and sometimes that does not seem very adequate. The typical example: which is the entropy rate of $X_n=$ digits of the decimal expansion of $\pi$?
For an alternative approach to defining the "average information" of a sequence (and hence some alternative "entropy"), using an operational (computational) instead of probabilistic setting, you might look into [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Relation_to_entropy)